# Ending the prompt when the answer is guessed correctly? The prompt will not end even when I click cancel

Tags: javascript, loops, prompt

Here is my assignment.

> Add a prevGuesses property to the game object initialized to an empty
> array Add a getGuess method to game that prompts the player to enter a
> guess with a message formatted as: Enter a guess between [smallestNum]
> and [biggestNum]:. Hint - use a template literal for the prompt
> message Ensure that the getGuess method returns a value that is:
>
> Is a number, not a string Is between smallestNum and biggestNum,
> inclusive Hints:
>
> This is a great use case for a while loop parseInt returns NaN if the
> string cannot be parsed into a number From within the play method,
> invoke the getGuess method and add the new guess to the
> prevGuesses array Add a render method to game that play will call after a
> guess has been made that alerts:
>
> If the secret has been guessed:
>
> Congrats! You guessed the number in [x] guesses! Otherwise:
>
> Your guess is too [high|low] Previous guesses: x, x, x, x Hints:
>
> render won't be able to access any of play's local variables, e.g.,
> guess, so be sure pass render any arguments as needed Template literals
> not only have interpolation, they honor whitespace - including line
> breaks! The list of previous guesses can be generated using the array
> join method The play method should end (return) when the guess matches
> secretNum

I'm thinking I need to add a `break;` to get the prompt to close after I guess the secret number correctly?

```
const game = {
    title: 'Guess the Number!',
    biggestNum: 100,
    smallestNum: 1,
    secretNum: null,
    prevGuesses: [],
    play: function () {
        this.secretNum = Math.floor(Math.random() *
            (this.biggestNum - this.smallestNum + 1)) + this.smallestNum;
        console.log(prevGuesses + getGuess);
    },
    getGuess: function () {

        do {

            var guess = parseInt(prompt(`Enter a guess between ${this.smallestNum} and ${this.biggestNum}:`));
            this.prevGuesses.push(guess);
            this.render(this.prevGuesses.slice(-1)[0], this.secretNum)
        } while (isNaN(guess) || guess < this.smallestNum || guess > this.biggestNum);
        //console.log('Guess: ', guess); 
    },
    render: function (guess, secretNum) {
        if (guess < secretNum) {
            alert(`Your guess is too low \n Previous guesses:${this.prevGuesses.join(', ')}`)

            this.getGuess()
        } else if (guess > secretNum) {
            alert(`Your guess is too high \n Previous guesses:${this.prevGuesses.join(', ')}`)

            this.getGuess()
        } else {
            alert(`Congrats! You guessed the number in ${this.prevGuesses.length} guesses!`);
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Welcome, D19m!  Can you please write a body to your question?  Your question will be closed unless you describe your problem including expected results, actual results, and describe what you've tried to do to solve your problem and where you got stuck.

Comment: will do, thank you

Comment: Note that the function `prompt` will either return the string that the user entered or will return `null` if the user clicked cancel so you should store this response in a variable and check it (before passing it to parseInt) See the documentation for [prompt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt)